# What's the shortcut in excel to show/hide cell comments?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

what's the shortcut in excel to show/hide cell comments?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

This works as a toggle command.

Comment: This is Ribbon shortcut. I prefer the classic one (Shift-F2), it still works with the Ribbon. :)

Comment: @thenonhacker it also puts the cursor in the comment though, so you have to do shift-f2 followed by escape twice.

Answer (score 5):

Shift-F2 to edit them... otherwise i think you have to use the right click options.

Comment: This does not show or hide the existing comments.

Answer (score 1):

A modification on Geoffrey van Wyk's VBS - toggles only comment of active cell

```
Sub Show_Hide_Comment()
'
' This macro toggles the display of selected cell's comment if one exists.
' It does not create one if there is none... for this press Ctl+F2
'
' You may use macros menu to set keyboard shortcut
'
  If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveCell.Comment.Visible Then
        ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
    Else
        ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Excel 2013 and on the ribbon's REVIEW tab I have a "Show/Hide Comment" to toggle visibility of a single cell's comment.

Shortcut: Alt, R, H

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007, there is no such keyboard shortcut according to the Excel Help File. You will have to write a macro for that.

```
Sub Show_Hide_Comments()
'
' This macro toggles the display of all comments that have been inserted for cells in a worksheet.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S

'
    If Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator Then
        Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
    Else
        Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
    End If

End Sub
```

You can paste the above code into a module in your Personal Workbook and set the shortcut in the Macros dialog. Let me know if you do not know how to do that.

Comment: -1? Why? Please explain.